# Bootstrap modal plugin close add routines

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello I just have maybe an easy question look this example:

[Link to bootstrap example](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_modal.asp)

Now in this line is my question:

```
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
```

The question is how can I make to add more routines after the user click on close. Actually that line makes that if the user click there just close the window but I want to add a sequence of other commands in JavaScript for example after the user clicks on close I want to reset some variables with commands like var variable="" and then jumps to a page. How can I add more commands to that button close if I have the exact line like the example I gave you?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can bind multiple times to an element with the same event (click in this case).  So long as none of the event handlers terminate the event bubbling, all the bound event handlers will be processed.

Comment: Yes but could you give an example using the example above? For example if user clicks on close make the var did="" simply like that and after close the window that's it how could you make that with code example?

Comment: It should just be another binding.  $('.close').on('click', function(){ /* do whatever you want, such as manipulate variable did */ });

Comment: Thank you so much is what I wanted know.